# Is Lucee Removing Request Header Cookies?

Tags: iis, cookies, lucee

I have a site running IIS 10, Lucee 5.2.7.63, using Oracle Webgate.  Webgate is me passing a cookie called OAMAuthNCookie_mysite.com:443, which I can see in Chrome Dev Tools as Request Header Cookies, but when I dump header variables, cookies, and all other scopes I can think of to a test page, I do not see that particular cookie.  I see CFID, CFTOKEN, and other cookies passed by Webgate, but I do not see that particular cookie, and I need that cookie and value.

Is Lucee removing this cookie somehow?  I've tried dumping cookie, request, and GetHTTPRequestData() and that cookie does not show up.  How is it available in DevTools, but not to Lucee?

Comment: Is the cookie on the same domain as the Lucee request?

Comment: It is, yes.  I also have Domain Cookies enabled in Lucee Admin

Comment: @andrewdixon I also noticed that the cookie in question has None under SameSite.  None of the other cookies have a value there.

Comment: You can track down the requests inside IIS via FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis That at least tells if IIS manipulates them.

Comment: Nothing appeared in FRT

Comment: My guess is that Oracle Webgate is intercepting the cookie for it's purposes and then disposing of it before passing on to the Lucee backend. There is no need for it beyond Webgate.

Comment: I was told I need it because all POSTs need to have it appended to the request, as I'm getting HTTP2 errors for Unauthorized POSTs